# How to move ACR from one subscription to another subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-container-registry

```
I have 3 ACR (All are in Seperate Subscription,Seperate Resource Group Name) and region is same.
I tried to import Repositores from ACR1-->ACR3 or ACR2-->ACR3.


I used below commands in powershell.
-------------------------
az acr import \
  --name <destinationRegistry> \
  --source <sourceRegistry>.azurecr.io/<Image:Tag> \
  --username <SourceRegistryUsername> \
  --password <SourceRegistryPassword>
  
-------------------------
$SourceAcrName=""
$DestinationAcrName=""
$Repos= az acr repository list --name $SourceAcrName | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($repo in $Repos) {
    $Tags = az acr repository show-tags -n $SourceAcrName --repository $repo | ConvertFrom-Json
    foreach ($tag in $Tags) {
        az acr import -r $SourceAcrName -n $DestinationAcrName --source "${repo}:${tag}" --no-wait
    }
}
```

/// Error i'm getting "The resource with name '***' and type 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries' could not be found in subscription '*** (*****-***-**-**-*******)'." ///

Comment: Are they in the same tenant?

Comment: With "move" do you mean importing the content from one registry into another (the command you listed above) or move the actual resource to another subscription?

Answer (score 0):

If ACR are in the same tenant you should use this command

```
az acr import \
  --name myregistry \
  --source aci-helloworld:latest \
  --image aci-hello-world:latest \
  --registry /subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/sourceResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/mysourceregistry
```

I assumed you already logged in into ACR's if not please provide parameters for service principal

```
  --username <SP_App_ID> \
  --password <SP_Passwd>
```